# No constant Logged time from biometric

Tags: reactjs

The figure above shows the activity log of attendance. As you can see, there is no constant total of 8 hours of duty for a regular employee. The first time is the logged-in time followed by the logged-out time. Using ReactJS, how can we calculate that each day, an employee must be logged in for a total of equal to or less than 8 hours?

[image]

expected result will be:

```
Attend. Logs
Date :      2024-01-01 ~ 2024-01-15
jovie
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
ralph
1
2 07:45 (login) 16:01 (logout)
3 07:53 (login) 16:03 (logout)
4 07:50 (login) 16:05 (logout)
5 07:52 (login) 16:01 (logout)
6 
7
8
9 07:46 (login) 16:00 (logout)
10 07:49 (login) 16:04(logout)
11 07:58  (login)  16:04    (logout)
12 07:56  (login)  16:00 (logout)
13
14
15 07:43 (login) (no logout)
kitt
1 00:02  (login) 07:40 (logout)
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
androw
1 
2 23:46 (login) 08:03  (logout next day)
3 23:52 (login)  08:16  (logout next day)
4
5 23:59 (login)  08:16  (logout next day)
6
7  15:31 (login)  00:00  (logout next day)
8 23:53  (login)    08:01(logout next day)
9
10 23:48 (login) 08:03(logout next day)
11 16:03(login) 08:03 (logout next day)
12 23:58 (login)  08:02 (logout next day)
13
14
15
```